# Create record from ModalBox in Community cloud using Aura Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller, modal

I have created an Aura component in Community that display a ModalBox allowing to create a record in Salesforce when submitting the info from the modalBox.
The problem I have is that when the record is created in Salesforce, the information entered in the modalbox are not inserted on the record in Salesforce.

[image]

Basically the fields Phone Number, Case Concern Category and Description are blank in Salesforce when the record is created.

I am pretty sure the problem is coming from the Apex Controller but I struggle to figure out how to write the code to capture the values inserted in the modalBox.

Thank you for your help

Here are the component and the controllers:

.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="CaseConcernController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="isConcernModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentCaseStatus" type="String" default="Open"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentCaseRecordType" type="String" default="Incident"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentCaseConcern" type="Integer" default="0"/>
<aura:attribute name="caseRec" type="Case" default="{'sObjectType':'Case'}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="large" aura:id="spinner" class="slds-hide" />    

<div>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.currentCaseRecordType=='Incident'}">
         
        <lightning:button label="Raise a Case Concern" class="concern"
                          iconName="utility:warning"
                          iconPosition="left"
                          title="Raise a Case Concern"
                          onclick="{! c.concernModalOpen }"
                          disabled="{!if(v.currentCaseCaseConcern>0,'true','false')}"/>
    </aura:if>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isConcernModalOpen}"> 
        
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open"> 
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1"> 
                    
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-text-align_center custom-container">
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-4 slds-max-small-size_2-of-2" style="text-align: left;padding-left: 2%;padding-right: 2%;">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">
                                <abbr class="slds-required" title="required" data-aura-rendered-by="148:2;a">*</abbr>Phone Number
                            </label>
                            <lightning:helptext content="Please, be aware the call will be done in English" />
                            <lightning:input variant="label-hidden" name="phone" required="true" value="{!v.caseRec.Phone_Number__c}"/>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-4 slds-max-small-size_2-of-2" style="text-align: left;padding-left: 2%;padding-right: 2%;">
                            <lightning:select name="select1" label="Case Concern Category" required="true" value="{!v.caseRec.Case_Concern_Category__c}">
                                <option value="">--None--</option>
                                <option value="No Solution Provided">No Solution Provided</option>
                                <option value="Unsatisfied Solution Provided">Unsatisfied Solution Provided</option>
                                <option value="Repetitive task">Repetitive task</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </lightning:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 2%;padding-right: 2%;">
                        <lightning:textarea name="desc" label="Description" required="true" value="{!v.caseRec.Description}"/>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral"
                                      label="Cancel"
                                      title="Cancel"
                                      onclick="{! c.concernModalCancel }"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand"
                                      label="Submit"
                                      title="Submit"
                                      onclick="{! c.concernModalSave}" />
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->
    </aura:if>        
</div>
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
concernModalOpen: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isConcernModalOpen", true);
},

concernModalCancel: function(component, event, helper) {
   component.set("v.isConcernModalOpen", false); 
},

concernModalSave: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('test recorId ', component.get('v.recordId'));
    console.log('test caseRec ', component.get('v.caseRec'));
    
    let action = component.get('c.createCaseConcern');
    action.setParams({
        caseRec: component.get('v.caseRec'),
        recordId: component.get('v.recordId')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data){
        let result = data.getReturnValue();
        $A.util.addClass(component.find('spinner'), 'slds-hide');
        if(result){
            component.set("v.isOpen", false);
            //window.location.href='/support/s/case/'+result;
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                'type':'success',
                "message": "Your case concern has been submitted successfully. A team member will contact you shortly."
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            return;
        }
    });
    $A.util.removeClass(component.find('spinner'), 'slds-hide');
    component.set('v.isConcernModalOpen', false);
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
                                           
},

doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    let action = component.get('c.getCurrentCaseStatus');
    action.setParams({
        recordId: component.get('v.recordId')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set('v.currentCaseStatus', data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    
    let action2 = component.get('c.getCurrentCaseRecordType');
    action2.setParams({
        recordId: component.get('v.recordId')
    });
    action2.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set('v.currentCaseRecordType', data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
    
    let action3 = component.get('c.getCurrentCaseConcern');
    action3.setParams({
        recordId: component.get('v.recordId')
    });
    action3.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set('v.currentCaseConcern', data.getReturnValue());
    });
}
})
```

apex controller

```
public class CaseConcernController {

@AuraEnabled
public static String createCaseConcern(String caseRec, String recordId) {
    
    Id recrdTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Case Concern').getRecordTypeId();
    System.debug('recordId debug ' +recordId);
    List<User> userList = [SELECT Name, ContactId, Contact.Name, UserType FROM USER WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
    
    Case currentCase = [SELECT Id,CaseNumber,Subject,ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id =:recordId LIMIT 1];
    //Case currentCase = [SELECT CaseNumber, ContactId, Subject FROM Case WHERE Id = '5000900000A0tYUAAZ'];

    Case cc = new Case(ParentId = recordId,
                       RecordTypeId = recrdTypeId,
                       Subject = 'Case Concern on : '+currentCase.CaseNumber+' '+currentCase.Subject);
   
    System.debug('Case Concern created: ' +cc.Subject);
    if(userList.size() > 0) {
        if(userList[0].UserType == 'Standard') {
          cc.ContactId = currentCase.ContactId;  
        } else {
            cc.ContactId = userList[0].ContactId;
        }  
    }
    insert cc;
    return cc.Id;
    
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getCurrentCaseStatus(String recordId) {
    Case c = [SELECT Status FROM Case WHERE Id =:recordId];
    return c.Status;  
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Integer getCurrentCaseConcern(String recordId) {
    Integer num = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE isClosed = false AND ParentId =:recordId];
    return num;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getCurrentCaseRecordType(String recordId) {
    Case c = [SELECT RecordType.Name FROM Case WHERE Id =:recordId];
    return c.RecordType.Name;
}  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to add the field on insert DML

add Phone Number, Case Concern Category and Description fields in case

```java
Case cc = new Case(
    ParentId = recordId,
    RecordTypeId = recrdTypeId,
    Subject = 'Case Concern on : ' + currentCase.CaseNumber + ' ' + currentCase.Subject
);
```